# Wrong attribution to second condition in permutation

Tags: python, function, loops, permutation

I want my code to print:

```
Backflip Complete
Backflip Hyper
180 Round Complete
180 Round Mega
Gumbi Complete
```

But it insteat prints:

```
Backflip Complete
Backflip Hyper
180 Round Complete
180 Round Hyper
Gumbi Complete
Gumbi Hyper
```

It looks like it only takes the first if argument for `landing` in `def landings(tricks)`, so all of the `tricks` are printing the `landing` for backflip, instead of a different argument for each of the `tricks`.

Why does it do this and how do I fix it? Is it getting iterated over or something or am I not assigning something correctly?

(Edit: I'm going to add a lot more variables and read these from an excel sheet, so I'd like to not manually type out each one like I did below. I just don't understand how to make it a tree so to say, and assign the dependencies correctly.)

My Code:

```
import itertools


backflip = "Backflip"
one80round = "180 Round"
gumbi = "Gumbi"
tricks = [backflip,one80round,gumbi]

complete = " Complete"
hyper = " Hyper"
mega = " Mega"

backflip_landing = [complete,hyper]
one80round_landing = [complete,mega]
gumbi_landing = [complete]


def landings(tricks):
    for i in tricks:
        if i == backflip:
            landing = backflip_landing
        elif i == one80round:
            landing = one80round_landing
        elif i == gumbi:
            landing = gumbi_landing
        return landing

    
for i in itertools.product(tricks, landings(tricks)): 
    print(i[0] + i[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate most of your variables since there is little point in having one variable for each string. You could also forget about itertools since you really don't want a product at all. Furthermore, the function `landings` can be replaced by a dictionary of the same name (the fact that you made `landings` a function of `tricks` rather than of individual tricks was one of your bugs). After making that dictionary, a simple nested for-loop prints what you want:

```
tricks = ['Backflip','180 Round','Gumbi']

landings = {'Backflip': ['Complete','Hyper'],
           '180 Round': ['Complete','Mega'],
           'Gumbi': ['Complete']}
    
for trick in tricks:
    for landing in landings[trick]:
        print(trick,landing, sep = ' ')
```

Output:

```
Backflip Complete
Backflip Hyper
180 Round Complete
180 Round Mega
Gumbi Complete
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of that. Once I figure out this part I'm going to change it so I'm reading an excel sheet . The main problem is I'm going to add more variables. So backflip has 2 possible landings, and both of those landings have 1-17 different transition options for the third variable and then only certain tricks are possible from those transitions for a second trick. Any help is appreciated.